# Solr search with synonyms

Tags: solr

Consider a `@companyName` field in a Solr schema. It's of type `string`. We have another Solr database (MongoDB, REST whatever) which contains the synonyms of company names. E.g. for `BT` `@companyName` a synonym would be `British Telecom`. We would like to run a Solr query `companyName:BT` which returns all matches including synonyms taken from external place. We're open to what external place should be.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you considered: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.SynonymFilterFactory ?

Answer (score 2):

As condit suggests, have a look at the `Synonym Filter`

- https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.SynonymFilterFactory
- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-SynonymFilter

If you have the synonyms you need within another database or some external system, export them into that file format Solr needs. There is (as of Solr 4.5) no such thing as "synonyms automatically loaded from other system"-feature.

Should the synonyms file change during runtime of your Solr server, you are required to reload your core before the new synonyms are considered. But be aware that just swapping the synonyms file will not change the indexed tokens. Just query time synonyms are affected without re-indexing.

[Better synonym handling in Solr](http://nolanlawson.com/2012/10/31/better-synonym-handling-in-solr) is a good write up about synonyms in Solr.

Comment: what about the ManagedSynonymFilterFactory ?

Comment: Good question @kozla13. This answer has aged. I would need to consider and write that up. Currently we are not using the ManagedSynonyms.